# htaccess migration from Apache to LiteSpeed

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, litespeed

my htaccess rules works fine in Apache but i had to change to LiteSpeed and my page doesnt work properly (eg if i type url like http://domain.com/article/some-article or http://domain.com/article/tags/some-tag). Maybe somebody coped with similar problem? In server logs i get : Maximum number of redirect reached.

My htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]     

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  .article.php/tags/([^/]+)$     [NC]
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$      article.php?tag=%1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  .article.php/([^/]+)$     [NC]
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$      article.php?art=%1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  .article.php/(.+)$     [NC]
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$      http://domain.com/article/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I will be grateful for your help

Comment: This is a good question! I wish someone would be able to answer as I am also having some issues with the differences in how Apache & Litespeed treat .htaccess rules.

Answer (score 0):

I show you how I coped with the problem - I had to change rules and order  - I think there  was some loop redirection:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NC]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  .articles/tags/([^/]+)$     [NC]
    RewriteRule  ^(.*)$      articles.php?tag=%1 [L,NC,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  .articles/([^/]+)$     [NC]
    RewriteRule  ^(.*)$      articles.php?article=%1 [L,NC,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  .articles.php/tags/([^/]+)$     [NC]
    RewriteRule  ^(.*)$      articles/tags/%1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  .articles.php/([^/]+)$     [NC]
    RewriteRule  ^(.*)$      articles/%1 [L,R=301]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # browser requests PHP
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]        

    #301 redirect error page (instead of 302 - for SEOD reason)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . /page-not-found [L,R=301] 

</IfModule>
```